# How to install dwm in Arch Linux

Tags: x-dwm

I installed [dwm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwm) 6.0 using the file provided [here](http://dwm.suckless.org/) and then...

```
# make install
# dwm
```

But running "dwm" gives error: "*dwm: cannot open display*".
I tried "exec dwm", but it starts a new login dialog, basically a new session.

Note: I installed a display manager, and I'm sure it's not a graphics card installation problem, because I tried the "awesome" window manager package and it worked.

Comment: You need to run `dwm` as the user with the X session running (not root like in that snippet) and when no other window manager is already running. Alternatively, you need to put that in your X session startup scripts or give it a login manager configuration entry.

Comment: Dwm is a "Window manager" - you can't just "run" it, like a normal program.  You need to configure X Windows to use it, then you need to restart X.  Look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dwm or https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109206

Comment: It did work and dwm started after editing .xinitrc. thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, you will need to install X server and Git (as root)

```
pacman -S xorg-xinit xorg git
```

Change directory to */usr/src* because you want this to apply to all users:

```
cd /usr/src
```

As root, clone suckless software such as dwm (window manager), st (recommended terminal), and dmenu (simple application menu)

```
git clone git://git.suckless.org/dwm
git clone git://git.suckless.org/st
git clone git://git.suckless.org/dmenu
```

Change directory into each one, and compile them:

```
cd dwm ## Do this step also with st and dmenu
sudo make clean install
```

Add a new user that is under the users group (as root):

```
useradd -m -g users ari
passwd ari
```

Log out, log in as new user, and execute:

```
<favorite text editor> .xinitrc
    from there, add "exec dwm" into the file, save, and exit
```

Start your session with:

```
startx
```

Comment: Kind of unrelated to an excellent answer, but `<your favorite editor>` should usually be `$EDITOR` ;)